# problem with elseif in velocity

Tags: velocity

I have this velocity template. It works fine in one case, but doesn't in another. If I remove the `elseif` it works fine. Has anyone encountered this?

```
#if (some condition)
     ## Do something 
#elseif
     ## Do something else
#end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know Velocity, but normally `elseif` is used with a second condition.

`else` seems to be what you need.

```
#if (some condition)
     ## Do something 
#else
     ## Do something else
#end
```

Comment: That's correct.  The right syntax would be #elseif (othercondition), or just use #else.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `#elseif` statement then you should make sure that you are checking some condition inside that `#elseif` statement.

Eg :-

```
#if (some condition)
     ## Do something 
#elseif (some condition)
     ## Do something
#else
     ## Do something else
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this:
[Apache Velocity User Guide](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#conditionals)

Basically it has to go according to one of the cases below:

```
#if ( condition )
    ##do something
#end

#if ( condition )
    ##do something
#else
    ##do something
#end

#if ( condition )
    ##do something
#elseif ( condition )
    ##do something
#else
    ##do something
#end
```

(The if-elseif-....-else ladder length can be long)